# Type mismatch error when trying to implement swipe views using ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm a newbie learning kotlin and android and I'm trying out simple swipe-able views with ViewPager2.

This is my adapter code:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(var images: List<Int>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>()
   {
        inner class ViewPagerViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewPagerBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
           val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_pager,parent,false)
           return ViewPagerViewHolder(bind(view))
       }

       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
           var curImage = images[position]
           holder.binding.imgview.setImageResource(curImage)

       }

       override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           return images.size
       }
   }
```

This is my MainActivity file where I'm getting the error:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        var image = listOf {
            R.drawable.illustration
            R.drawable.pexelsphoto
            R.drawable.preview
            R.drawable.wallpaper
            R.drawable.yh
        }


        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(image)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

        binding.viewPager.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL

    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting on the image variable in the ViewPagerAdapter parenthesis

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<() -> Int> but List<Int> was expected
```

I'm unable to find any solution online on how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the image list in wrong way, it must be like this

```
var image = listOf (
            R.drawable.illustration,
            R.drawable.pexelsphoto,
            R.drawable.preview,
            R.drawable.wallpaper,
            R.drawable.yh
        )
```

The expected type is `List<Int>` and it is defined like above. Meanwhile you use `listOf {}` which is `List<() -> Int>` type.